# Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, dropdown

I'm using ng-bootstrap as a substitute for ui-bootstrap in angular2.

My html is as follows:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li class="tag" ngb-dropdown auto-close="outsideClick" 
        *ngFor="let item of ['Elastic Search','Database Theory','CVS'];
        let $index=index;" 
        [ngClass]="{'default-tag': $index==0, 'matched-tag': $index==1, 'unmatched-tag': $index==2 }">
         <a href ngb-dropdown-toggle id="desiredSkill{{$index}}">
             <i class="bi_interface-tick following"></i> {{item}} <i class="bi_interface-more tag-menu-icon"></i>
                            </a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu tag-menu" ngb-dropdown-menu [aria-labelledby]="desiredSkill{{$index}}">
                     <li><a href>Follow Skill</a></li>
                     <li><a href>Related Jobs</a></li>
                </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

But when I run my app I get following error:

> main.browser.ts:25Error: Template parse errors:
>       Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 12 in [desiredSkill{{$index}}] in
>   JobDescription@174:77 ("                  
>                               ][aria-labelledby]="desiredSkill{{$index}}">
>
> "): JobDescription@174:77
>       Parser Error: Unexpected token '{' at column 13 in [desiredSkill{{$index}}] in JobDescription@174:77 ("
>   
>                               ][aria-labelledby]="desiredSkill{{$index}}">
>
> "): JobDescription@174:77
>       Can't bind to 'aria-labelledby' since it isn't a known property of 'ul'. ("                  
>                               ][aria-labelledby]="desiredSkill{{$index}}">
>
> "): JobDescription@174:77
>       Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 12 in [desiredSkill{{$index}}] in
>   JobDescription@174:77 ("
>
> ```
>                 <div class="row">
>                   <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4" [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let i of [0,1,3]">
>                     <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81VFU9"):
> ```
>
> JobDescription@215:49
>       Parser Error: Unexpected token '{' at column 13 in [desiredSkill{{$index}}] in JobDescription@174:77 ("
>
> ```
>                 <div class="row">
>                   <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4" [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let i of [0,1,3]">
>                     <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81VFU9"):
> ```
>
> JobDescription@215:49
>       Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 12 in [desiredSkill{{$index}}] in
>   JobDescription@174:77 ("        
>                     ERROR ->="main.applyJob()">Apply for job
>                     
>                     ERROR ->="main.applyJob()">Apply for job
>                     
>                     ][hidden]="!ifNotApplied">Applied 
>                     
>                     ][hidden]="!ifNotApplied">Applied 
>                     
>                     ][hidden]="!ifNotUploaded">Upload CV
>                     
>                     ][hidden]="!ifNotUploaded">Upload CV
>                     
>                   Have questions about this job?
>
> [ERROR ->]
>                     
>                       
>                   Have questions about this job?
>                   [ERROR ->]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can't use interpolation inside standard property binding. There should be an expression.

Seems it should be:

```typescript
[attr.aria-labelledby]="'desiredSkill' + $index"
```

or

```typescript
attr.aria-labelledby="desiredSkill{{$index}}"
```

Answer (score 12):

Usually this error occurs when we are trying to implement both Interpolation and Property data binding on the same html property.

Example:

Wrong implementation

```
[disabled]= {{isDisabled}}
```

Correct implementation

```
disabled= {{isDisabled}}
```

Note: remove the square bracket from the html element property

Comment: This didn't work for me, it resulted in `error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'`, even though the property `isDisabled` was defined as a boolean. I was able to solve both that and the OP's error with: `[disabled]="isDisabled"`

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" title="Edit" (click)="showEditModal(record.id)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to declare **`index`** of **`ngFor`**

```
*ngFor="let item of ['Elastic Search','Database Theory','CVS'];let $index=index" ...
```

also use,

```
[attr.aria-labelledby]="desiredSkill{{$index}}"
```

Comment: can you try with `[attr.aria-labelledby]="desiredSkill{{$index}}"`?

Comment: That is not a solution if I'll add it to attr then ngb-bootstrap will ignore its value and it will be just added the attribute to the element

Comment: Oh I see. try other answer provided by yurzui.

Answer (score 1):

If you want pass only $index value

```
[attr.aria-labelledby]=" ' ' + $index"
```

Answer (score 0):

In link tags use like this

Use this

```
<a  class="custom-badge status-blue" [routerLink]="'/hospital/doctorleave/'+item.Id]">Manage Leave</a>
```

Instead of

```
<a  class="custom-badge status-blue" [routerLink]="'/hospital/doctorleave/{{item.Id}}']">Manage Leave</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me changing this

`<img [src]="{{picture.name}}" [alt]="picture. caption"/>`

To this:

`<img src="{{picture.name}}" alt="picture.caption"/>`

Solved the problem. The problem was this -> [] around the properties i.e src and alt in the html/template file.