# Angular 4: Bootstrap's collapse does not work using data-target attribute

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am still new to Angular 4 (using Angular-CLI). I somehow do not manage to get simple Bootstrap Collapse work.

The following is my code for the collapse:

```
<div *ngFor="let idea of ideas" class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">{{ idea.title }}</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <cite>{{ idea.author }}</cite>
    <p>{{ idea.description }}</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#'+idea._id" aria-expanded="false" [attr.aria-controls]="idea._id">More</button>
  </div>
  <div [attr.id]="idea._id" class="collapse"><p>Show Details</p></div>
</div>
```

**Update:**

I did import all the relevant Bootstrap and jQuery scripts.  As you can see below, the IDs do match. I don't know why it does not work? Is there an issue with Angular 5 and Bootstrap's Collapse?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What's the version of bootstrap?

Comment: Did you inspect the rendered HTML to ensure the `data-target` and `id` attributes are properly set?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: From your description everything should work. So I think you didn't provide here important detail to let us help you. Could you please share your example via https://github.com/ or http://plnkr.co/ ?

Comment: What error are you getting? Please update with screenshot.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap Version 3.3.7. and Angular 5.2.7.

Comment: @ZimSystem: no, I did not yet inspect the rendered version. Maybe there is a mismatch between data-target value and id.

Answer (score 10):

I was facing a similar issue with **Angular 5** and **Bootstrap 4**, when I was trying to make collapsibles in `*ngFor`. After debugging I found that `data-target="#someId"` is rendered as `target="#someId"` and that's why the bootstrap collapse wasn't working.

I found my solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40203518/3070768). The solution to your specific question would be to use:

```
attr.data-target="#{{idea._id}}"
```

Comment: I faced this issue with Angular 6 and attr.data-target is being rendered as attr.data-target also, do you know how to fix this with Angular 6?

Comment: I could help by seeing the code maybe... Something else could be the cause of the problem @SherwinAblañaDapito

Comment: hero ! You saved my day

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to replace `[attr.data-target]="'#collapse'+index"` with `[attr.data-bs-target]="'#collapse'+index"`

I also replaced `data-parent` with `data-bs-parent` and `data-toggle` with `data-bs-toggle`.

The issue was I didn't have the -bs- but neither does the example given on the  site: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/

I found this out by comparing it against the page source code on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/sidebars/#

I am on Bootstrap 5.1.3 and those docs are for 4.3 so perhaps this is a Bootstrap version issue, but this comment might help me or someone fix this issue again later.

Answer (score -1):

The first issue that I see here is that you are missing JQuery. If you have included, then you might have done it after bootstrap.js(min.js). You should fix that as it is required primarily to toggle elements.

After Reading your comments I see where the problem is. You are using bootstrap 3 and looking at examples of bootstrap 4 to achieve what you want.

For bootstrap 3, you need to use href="#id" to toggle it instead of data-target="#id".

Comment: Is this the issue? Wrong bootstrap version?