# String containing <br> doesn't break line with ngFor

Tags: angular, frontend

I iterate through an array with ngFor. The array contains strings like this: "Some Text 1 `<br>` some text 2". Here is the HTML:

`<div class="content" *ngFor="let item of graphService.contents">{{item}}</div>`

It prints the correct text but doesn't break the line. It prints the br like a normal word but I want it to break the line. How can I achieve that without splitting the string in two like "Array.firstString + `<br>` + Array.secondString?

Comment: If your item contains html then you have to use https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent escaping HTML u can do :

```
    <div class="content" 
         *ngFor="let item of graphService.contents"
         [innerHTML]="item"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```html
<div class="content" *ngFor="let item of graphService.contents">
    <div [innerHTML]="item"></div>
</div>
```

If you want to render a plain text from rich text then you can add this function.

```js
this.utilService.htmlToPlaintext(content);
```

Define a function `htmlToPlaintext()` like this in your service.

```js
htmlToPlaintext(text) {
    var plain = text ? String(text).replace(/\\t/g, '') : '';
    return text ? String(plain).replace(/\\n/g, '') : '';
  }
```

Comment: "Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected" is the error i get when i try to do it with [innerHTML]

Comment: then you can once refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203279/parser-error-got-interpolation-where-expression-was-expected

Comment: Try once by giving  [innerHTML]="item"

Comment: Your answer didn't solve my prolem but the error it threw got me on the right track.

Comment: Yeah by mistake i binded the value item in double braces. That was the problem. Thanks