# How to use css calc() in angular style binding using variables from the component

Tags: css, reactjs, angular

How do I use the **Angular** style binding syntax with the css `calc()` function for dynamically setting the `width` of an element.

With **React** I could simply write :-

```
<div style = {{
   width: `calc((${currentStep - 1 } * (100% / ${steps - 1})) - 6px)`
}}>

</div>
```

With **Angular** I want to accomplish the same thing :-

```
<div
[style.width] = `calc((${currentStep - 1 } * (100% / ${steps - 1})) - 6px)`
>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @AbuSufian, That dosen't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

`[style. width]="getWidth(currentStep, steps)"`

Comment: Thanks Yugi, That doesn't work either, how ever this approach works with ngStyle. But the problem is I want to use the [style.width[] approach without having a method in my class file

Comment: That is impossible in angular, you can't use [..]={{..}}
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203279/parser-error-got-interpolation-where-expression-was-expected

Comment: You can do `style.width="stuff with {{}}"`, though; it's just the [bracket\] syntax you can't use. But since you can't use the `calc` built-in, it doesn't really help matters.